# Visual studio, fill space

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

In my form I put three charts. I want to fill all available space, and tried to set dock fill, but in this case the charts overlaps each other. I want, instead, to have every chart next to others.

How can I fill all the space, without overlaps?

Comment: Hi there are you using windows forms, wpf or something else ?

Comment: May use a panel to nest your charts in ?

Comment: i'm using windows forms, with panel i have the same problem, becaus each panel, when set "fill", overlaps the other panels.

Comment: Use `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel` as parent control for your charts.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you want to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`. Below are two examples of `TableLayoutPanel` which may be better because you can more easily control the desired layout.

The examples below use panels instead of grids but the idea is the same for whatever control you want to put inside the TableLayoutPanel.

In both examples, the `Dock` property of the `TableLayoutPanel` and all 3 components is set to `Fill`. This will cause everything to resize automatically as the form resized. Additionally, there is a `Rows` property and `Columns` property on the `TableLayoutPanel` which will allow you to set either pixels are percentages of the table a cell should consume.

**Example 1:** 3 panels side by side

[image: TableLayoutPanel with Panels]

**Example 2:** 2 panels above a third panel. In this case you set the `ColumnSpan` property to 2 on *Panel 3*

[image]